# Word breaks at a parentheses within the word ex. (im)possible

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, typesetting, formatting

i recently got an offer to do a quick catalogue for an artist and there is a point in his text with a parentheses in it ex. (im)possible.

indesign is breaking the word into:

blah blah one line (im) *break*

possible blah blah second line

im looking for any way to stop this from happening, as it is an artists catalogue and something i cannot simply remove from the text.
i appreciate any and all help.
thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll just leave a comment because this is off the top of my head and I don't have access to InDesign now...have you tried "remove discretionary hyphen"?

Answer (score 3):

Two things you can try:

1. Turn off hyphenation in the paragraph style.
2. Select the '(im)possible' broken across two lines, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and type 'No Break', then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

What you see below is an automated Grep Style setup, with no manual selection done. Bits of text can be made to stick together whatever you do with the text box.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: perfect, thank you so much, my graphics teacher never taught me such a thing. my graphics never taught me anything of the sort.

Comment: You could also use `\(\w+\)\w+` (left parenthesis followed by one or more letters followed by right parenthesis followed by one or more letters) as a more general solution so you don't have to add every word manually.